# Composite functions with domain and codomains

Tags: functions

a: $ \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $a(x) = (x/2) + 1$

b: $\mathbb{Z} \to \{0,1\}$ defined by $$b(x) = \begin{cases}  1 \qquad \text{ if } x \geq 1   \\  0 \qquad  \text{ if }  x \leq 0  \end{cases} $$

Does the composite function $a(b(x))$ exist?

According to my understanding this should exist as the range of $b$ which is $\{0,1\}$ is in the domain of a which is the $\mathbb{R}$. Can someone confirm this? If so how would you write the new equation with its new domain, co-domain and range?

Comment: Yes. The range of $b$ is inside the domain of $a$, so composition $a \circ b$ is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Simply we have  $$ a \circ b : \mathbb{Z} \longmapsto \mathbb{R} $$
defined by   $$ a \circ b (x) = \begin{cases}    \frac{3}{2} & \text{if} \; x\geq 1 \\
1   & \text{if} \; x\leq 0 \\   \end{cases} $$
The domain is  $\mathbb{Z} $, the co-domain is  $\mathbb{R} $ and the range is  $\{ 1,\frac{3}{2}  \}$.

Comment: To denote $\mathbb{Z}$, type \mathbb{Z} between dollar signs.  To denote $\mathbb{R}$, type \mathbb{R} between dollar signs.